# Filter row records based on particular date format in pyhon

Tags: pandas

Can anyone help me python code for filter records after particular date present in csv file,date column,having format DD/MM/YY-HH:MM:SS

Comment: Maybe, you should update your post with the first top lines of your csv file, publish what have you try so far to solve your problem and the expected result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion, upcoming clarifications i will take care.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), and about [Voting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [Accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Content of `filter_df_by_date.csv` file is presented below. Dates are in `DD/MM/YY-HH:MM:SS` format.

```
date,data
01/01/22-10:15:32,A
01/03/22-12:10:15,B
```

Possible solution is the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# read data from csv file and parse dates to datetime format
df = pd.read_csv("filter_df_by_date.csv", parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True)
df
```

[image]

```
# filter dataframe by date column
df = df[(df['date'] > '2022-01-02')]
# or if you need to be more precise
# df = df[(df['date'] > '2022-01-02 00:00:00')]
df
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Its working little bit improvement for comparison using below one        
df = df[(df['date'] > '2022-01-02 00:00:00')]

Comment: Hi, I believe `2022-01-02` equals to `2022-01-02 00:00:00` in this case as far as time set to zeros.

Comment: Yes sure,if required to check next case with HH or MM or DD just only change respective one same logic will be useful